# How to put resourse name in FlatFileItemWriter dynamically

Tags: java, spring-batch

I want to add the resource name dynamically in the ItemWriter, A prefix of the name comes from the stored procedure called in the ItemReader.
On each read the value will be different so that it will automatically create a different file.
Here is the snippet:-

```
<bean id="achFlatFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['settlementTimestamp']}**#{VALUE_FROM_READER}**.MPS.txt" />
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="writeToFile" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="format" value="%s" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Here VALUE_FROM_READER will come from reader,
I tried by adding the value to the job context through listeners, It is not helpful . Any approach will be appreciated.

Comment: Will you have one output file per input record? Or are you routing input records to a limited set of output files, depending on a value in the input record?

Comment: Yup, each record will have only one  specific output file. According to the no of input records ,I need to add the prefix of (A-Z) in the file name with the date.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Say you have 10.000 input records, do you have 10.000 output files? Or 26 files (one per A-Z prefix). In the latter case you can probably use a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`.

Comment: @jimmyPraet, In fact in reader i call a stored procedure which returns a list of objects, and depending upon the list size i need to write them in the same number of writer files. If the procedure returns 3 objects then I must write them to three different files with the suffix as A/B/C in the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" did the trick.

Here is the detail

In JOB-

```
<chunk reader="achFileHeaderReader" processor="achFileContentProcessor" writer="achFileContentWriter" commit-interval="1" >
                <streams>
                    <stream ref="AItemWriter" />
                    <stream ref="BItemWriter" />
                    <stream ref="CItemWriter" />
                </streams>
            </chunk>
```

Writer BEAN-

```
<bean id="classifier"  class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
<property name="routerDelegate">
    <bean class="com.abc.myabc.writer.ItemCodeClassifier" >
        <property name="contextInjector" ref="stepExecutionContextInjector"></property>
    </bean>
</property>
<property name="matcherMap">
    <map>
    <entry key="A" value-ref="AItemWriter" />
    <entry key="B" value-ref="BItemWriter" />
    <entry key="C" value-ref="CItemWriter" />
    </map>
</property>
</bean>
```

1.Inside ItemCodeClassifier write your logic for returning the resource suffix String.

2.Inject the delegate beans to the AItemWriter,BItemWriter,CItemWriter respectively with different resource name.

One dis advantage so far is you have to hard code different ItemWriters

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bean which contains the resource.
You set it in your reader and read it in your writer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using JavaConfig, use a Property in Config file, set it in Reader and read it in writer. I have quickly setup my env so you can improve the scoping of the rosource name property to avoid multiple/concurrent read/write.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
....

public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }

.....

@Bean
      public ItemReader<GeData> reader() throws Exception {     
        JdbcCursorItemReader<GeData> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<GeData>();
        reader.setDataSource(DBConfiguration.getDataSource());
        reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
        reader.setSql("....");
        setResourceName("resourceNameFromReader.txt");
        return reader;
    }

......
......

@Bean
    public ItemWriter<GeData> writer(DataSource dataSource) {   
        MyItemWriter writer = new MyItemWriter();  
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("E:\\" + getResourceName()));
        return writer;
    }
```

I have tried it in my configuration and its working. Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do it in XML configuration, Sorry for the silly questions ,I'm new to spring.